# Access a row based on two or more values in a row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

This should be a very simple question, but I just don't know how to do this.
I want to delete certain rows of my data.frame. how can i access a row based on the values of two columns?

```
DATE <- c("01.01.2000","02.01.2000","03.01.2000","06.01.2000","07.01.2000","09.01.2000","10.01.2000","01.01.2000","02.01.2000","04.01.2000","06.01.2000","07.01.2000","09.01.2000","10.01.2000")
RET <- c(-2.0,1.1,3,1.4,-0.2, 0.6, 0.1, -0.21, -1.2, 0.9, 0.3, -0.1,0.3,-0.12)
COMP <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
df <- data.frame(DATE, RET, COMP)

df

# DATE   RET COMP
# 1  01.01.2000 -2.00    A
# 2  02.01.2000  1.10    A
# 3  03.01.2000  3.00    A
# 4  06.01.2000  1.40    A
# 5  07.01.2000 -0.20    A
# 6  09.01.2000  0.60    A
# 7  10.01.2000  0.10    A
# 8  01.01.2000 -0.21    B
# 9  02.01.2000 -1.20    B
# 10 04.01.2000  0.90    B
# 11 06.01.2000  0.30    B
# 12 07.01.2000 -0.10    B
# 13 09.01.2000  0.30    B
# 14 10.01.2000 -0.12    B
```

Let's say I want to delete the row where DATE is "07.01.2000" and COMP is "A". If I could do something like:

```
df["07.01.2000" %in% df$DATE and "A" %in% COMP, ] <- NULL
```

would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't delete a row by assigning NULL. You can create a new data.frame that does not contain those values. Something like

```
df[!(df$DATE=="07.01.2000" & df$COMP =="A"), ]
```

If you have more dates or comps such that you really wanted to use `%in%` just realize that you have your parameters flipped. So

```
df[!(df$DATE %in% "07.01.2000" & df$COMP %in% "A"), ]
```

is the way to go.